# What does "runs on UI thread" for onPostExecute() really mean?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-asynctask

Consider an AsyncTask started in an Activity. What happens if the Activity is paused or destroyed? Will onPostExecute() run? If yes, what UI thread will be used?

Just wondering.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: `onPostExcecute` will run but throw an Exception for trying to run on a dead Thread if your Activity is destroyed. If you have an AsyncTask running when your activity might be shut down, consider moving your code to a service or using a loader.

Comment: in case Activity destroyed : It will be crashed because it lost the reference with origin Activity. Incase Activity paused, it still run on that Activity. For this scenario : you should use intent service , and get result via Broadcast.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

UI thread is available throughout the visible life of your application which may span on a combination of multiple activities.

Anything you change in views must be performed on UI thread and **onPostExecute** of *AsyncTask* reflects the same logic by executing the instructions inside on UI thread.

You may use **runOnUiThread** in your own `Thread` to make changes on Views. But since *AsyncTask* has **onPostExecute** method (which also runs on UI thread) so you dont logically need to use **runOnUiThread** there.

---

**Update**

Regarding your question: Yes, *onPostExecute* will still be called (because its invoked by a separate thread) even if your activity is destroyed and if the method will manipulate Views, you'll simply get **Force Close** error because reference to your activity is not available anymore.

Answer (score 1):

It will crash in `onPostExecute()` because of UI thread like a process Dialog. It happens to me, my Activity destroy before my Asynctask completes. It says "window leaked....." So, I remove `onPostExecute()`. No more crash..

Answer (score 0):

Remember to call cancel function to be void of exception in you onPause or onDestroyed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Wagas answer together with your tip will give me an idea how to enhance my current design even further.